# Scroll a long image

Tags: android, ios, midi

I would like to scroll a long image in sync with a midi file. Is there a way to tag/map these together with midi times or events so they stay aligned? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**iOS:**

The `UIImageView` rendering your image can be put inside a `scrollViewContentView: UIView` that is the only child to a `UIScrollView`, where the size of `scrollViewContentView` equals the size of the image.

Then you need to somehow draw a timeline for your midi file. Maybe you can use some third party lib for drawing this timeline as a chart? There are several iOS projects on Github for this, maybe [this](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) will work. Btw is this Swift of ObjC?

You will then need to put the view representing your timeline *side by side* with the `UIImageView` and with the same size.